# Selenium to click Images link on Google and click first image

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the below code. When I execute this,

1. Firefox opens - Expected
2. Go to Google.com - Expected
3. Keys in Pluralsight logo on searchbox - expected
4. I do not know what happens then I see the Google.com page with no text in searchbox.

However, when I put breakpoint and step in line by line I see it clicks Images. So, what is wrong when I execute it without breakpoints?

Another question I have is, once I am on the Images screen, how do I make my script click on the 1st image? I see the class name is **rg_ic rg_i** but I cannot use this as it has spaces. The ID keeps changing everytime. So, how can I click the 1st image? I commented it for now because I cannot get it to work.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Url = "http://google.com";
            var searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            searchBox.SendKeys("Pluralsight logo");
            searchBox.Submit();
            var imageLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Images"));
            imageLink.Click();
            //var firstImage = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("rg_ic"))[0];
            //firstImage.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working fine in c# selenium. for image 1 you can search by id as mentioned in answer

Answer (score 0):

the image id's are constant, and I ran a successful test using this (granted I'm using python, but the syntax is similar):

```
driver.get("http://google.com")
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_box.send_keys("Pluralsight logo")
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(4)
first_img = driver.find_element_by_id("dimg_1").click()
```

You have to provide time for the image to load. You could do this with an expected condition or just an explicit wait. Hope this helps.